# Surface area of sphere within a cylinder

Tags: real-analysis, integration, surfaces, surface-integrals, parametrization

I have to

> Compute the surface area of that portion of the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=a^2$ lying within the cylinder $\Bbb{T}:=\ \ x^2+y^2=by.$

My work:

I start with only the $\Bbb{S}:=\ \ z=\sqrt{a^2-x^2-y^2}$ part and will later multiply it by $2$.

$${\delta z\over \delta x}={-x\over \sqrt{a^2-x^2-y^2}}\ ;\ {\delta z\over \delta y}={-y\over \sqrt{a^2-x^2-y^2}}$$

Using the formula $$a(\Bbb{S})=\iint\limits_\Bbb{T}\sqrt{1+\left({\delta z\over \delta x}\right)^2+\left({\delta z\over \delta y}\right)^2}dx \ dy$$

I get $$a(\Bbb{S})=\iint\limits_{x^2+y^2=by}\sqrt{1+{by\over a^2-by}}\ dy\  dx\\=\int_0^{b/2}\int\limits_{{b\over 2}-\sqrt{{b^2\over 4}-x^2}}^{{b\over 2}+\sqrt{{b^2\over 4}-x^2}}\sqrt{1+{by\over a^2-by}}\ dy\  dx\\=a\int_0^{b/2}\int\limits_{{b\over 2}-\sqrt{{b^2\over 4}-x^2}}^{{b\over 2}+\sqrt{{b^2\over 4}-x^2}}{1\over\sqrt{a^2-by}}dy \ dx\\=a\int_0^{b/2}\left\{\left[{-2\sqrt{a^2-by}\over b}\right]_{{b\over 2}-\sqrt{{b^2\over 4}-x^2}}^{{b\over 2}+\sqrt{{b^2\over 4}-x^2}}\right\}\ dx$$

How to proceed now?The integral seems too bad.

**OR**

Is there a simpler parametrization ?

Comment: I feel like you should be completing the square first...

Comment: @SeanRoberson Will it help much? I dont know.. it still will be a nasty equation..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your derivatives are wrong by a factor of $2$. This causes your integrand to be 
$$
\sqrt{1-{x^2+y^2\over a^2-x^2-y^2}}=\frac a{\sqrt{a^2-x^2-y^2}}
$$ 
If we represent the cylinder in polar coordinates, we have $$r^2=b r \sin\theta.$$After cancelling $r$, we get $r=b\sin\theta$. So the interior of the cylinder is the region
$$
0\leq\theta\leq\pi,\ \ \ 0\leq r\leq b\sin\theta
$$
(the restriction on $\theta$ comes from $\sin\theta\geq r/b\geq0$). So the area is 
\begin{align}
a(\Bbb{S})&=\iint\limits_\Bbb{T}\sqrt{1+\left({\partial z\over \partial x}\right)^2+\left({\partial z\over \partial y}\right)^2}dx \ dy\\ \ \\
&=\int_0^\pi\int_0^{b\sin\theta}\frac {ar}{\sqrt{a^2-r^2}}\,dr\,d\theta\\ \ \\
&=-a\,\int_0^\pi \left.\vphantom{\int}{\sqrt{a^2-r^2}}\,\right|_0^{b\sin\theta}\,d\theta\\ \ \\
&=a\,\int_0^\pi \left(a-{\sqrt{a^2-b^2\sin^2\theta}}\right)\,d\theta\\ \ \\
&=a^2\pi-a\int_0^\pi {\sqrt{a^2-b^2\sin^2\theta}}\,d\theta.\\ \ \\
\end{align}
This last integral is an elliptic integral (unless $b=a$). It looks to me like all approaches to this problem will lead to this integral (I will be happy to be proven wrong, though).

Comment: It was very silly of me to commit such a mistake. However I have corrected it, and arrived at something further(edited in the question itself) . However it still looks nasty. Can you shed some light upon my approach? (Obviously the polar coordinate approach is much better +1)

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I can say anything about it. I actually tried to go through with that earlier today, and I didn't get anywhere.

Comment: Never mind! :-)  your approach is wonderful..

Comment: I think you forgot an $a$ before the last integral in the last line.

Comment: Yes I did. Thanks.

Comment: @MartinArgerami, how did you figure out that theta is from 0 to $\pi$?

Comment: It is explained in the answer! In any case, if you think about it, the cylinder has $y\geq0$. This is equivalent to $\sin\theta\geq0$.

Answer (score 5):

Another approach in spherical coordinates: parametrize the surface with
\begin{cases}
x=a \sin\phi \cos\theta \\
y=a \sin\phi \sin\theta \\
z=a \cos\phi 
\end{cases}

with $(\theta,\phi)\in [0,\pi]\times[0,\Phi]$, where $\Phi \in ]0,\pi]$ is the solution to
\begin{cases}
x^2+y^2+z^2=a^2 \\
x^2+y^2=by
\end{cases}
Substituting $x,y,z$ by their expressions in spherical coordinates yields
$$
\Phi = \sin^{-1}\left(\frac{b}{a}\sin\theta\right)
$$
It follows that 
$$
S=\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_0^{\Phi} a^2\sin\phi\; d\phi d\theta = a^2 \int_0^{\pi}1-\cos\Phi\; d\theta
$$
With a little trigonometric work ($\cos x =\pm \sqrt{1-\sin^2x}$), we can show that 
$$
\cos\Phi = \sqrt{1-\left(\frac{b}{a}\sin\theta\right)^2}
$$
Therefore
$$
S = \pi a^2 - a \int_0^{\pi} \sqrt{a^2-b^2\sin^2\theta}\; d\theta
$$

Comment: Another lovely approach. +1

Comment: So you answer more than just optimisation. :)) Hey, catch up to my rep already!

Comment: @BCLC hehe doing my best :) Cheers

Comment: Why did you not say directly $\cos\phi = \sqrt{1-\left(\frac{b}{a}\sin\theta\right)^2}$ ? I mean if you plug the corresponding values into the equation $x^2 + y^2 = by$, we are getting $\cos\phi = \sqrt{1-\left(\frac{b}{a}\sin\theta\right)^2}$ , so why are we not using it ?

Comment: @Leth: $\Phi$ is the angle at which the sphere and the cylinder intersect. To find it you have to solve the system $\{x^2+y^2+z^2=a^2, x^2+y^2=by \}$.

Comment: @Kuifje it gives me the same answer.