# Determine the area of a semisphere cut by a cylinder

Tags: surface-integrals, parametrization

Semisphere has the ecuation $z=\sqrt{16-x^2-y^2}$ and the cylinder $x^2+(y-2)^2=4$

Should I parametrize the sphere with trig functions or leave it as $\vecΣ = (x,y,\sqrt{16-x^2-y^2})$?

How do I procced then?

[Semisphere and cylinder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNHgl.png)

Comment: Please look at this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1993279/surface-area-of-sphere-within-a-cylinder